# RequestParser: Cannot Parse Dictionary Argument

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

When trying to pass in a dictionary object into a request, the `RequestParser` throws a 400 error and, using {error_msg}", returns the following error:

> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

The way that I'm trying to parse the argument is below:

```py
patch_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
# ...
patch_parser.add_argument("labels", type=dict, help="{error_msg}", store_missing=False)

# some POST/PUT request function
@app.route('/path/<id:int>')
def someFunction():
  args = patch_parser.parse_args()
  # ...
```

The code leading up to making the request:

```py
toUpdateWith = {"name": "Test", "description": "This is a test."}
toUpdateWith['labels'] = { "4" : "create"}
response = self.conn.post('/path/2', data=toUpdateWith)
```

The passed in data is:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "This is a test.",
  "labels": { 
    "4": "create"
  }
}
```

While this works fine via Postman, it doesn't work when doing it programmatically.  So, why exactly is this error occurring?

If there's any information that I'm missing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an argument that takes a dictionary, you'll need to pass data via json instead.

```py
toUpdateWith = {"name": "Test", "description": "This is a test."}
toUpdateWith['labels'] = { "4" : "create"}
response = self.conn.post('/path/2', json=toUpdateWith)
```